# can´t modify foreign key relations via Database Diagram

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a key with foreign relations which I want to add a cascade delete on. I am using SQL server management studio 2012.

I have seen a lot of guides saying I can easily do this via Database Diagram but when I right click to modify the key it doesn´t show the modify option. Do I need to install anything or am I missing something?

The following screenshot shows what I get when I right click the key.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you don't have the required permissions

Comment: how do I check that or how do I make sure that I have the right permissions?